# Migration from MySQL to Aurora; tmp database missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

we were on MySQL 5.6 ; and today migrated to Aurora using snapshot.. All database schemas are present in new aurora database ; except tmp  !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Aurora Cluster, tmp schema is excluded from file as table emulation. Therefore, users can't see any table in tmp schema when
1) users access restored cluster
2) users access reader node

The tmp database is excluded from snapshots, so the recommendation is to not use "tmp" name as a table name or database name in your database.

Anyway if you have such database/schema; you need to export and import them manually using mysqldump utility.. Even that created some issues..

So, the final solution I took was to change tmp schema name to tempo ..

Comment: Did you answer you own question one minute later? Wiki-style?

Comment: Yes.. I spent loads of time finding the root cause; so I feel its a good idea to share with everyone

Comment: Do you have a citation from the docs or an official answer from the help forums reflecting this information?